# Error when creating a new COM Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, com

My problem is that I'm trying to develop a Web API with C#, all that works fine, however my project needs to create an object from a dll and I get certain errors listed below.

The code I want to execute is the following:

```
namespace AccessControl.Objects
{
    public class DUMMY
    {
        private static AxSBXPCLib.AxSBXPC _Machine;

        public DUMMY(int machineNumber, string ip, int port, string name)
        {
            initObject(machineNumber, ip, port, name);
            _Machine.ConnectTcpip(machineNumber, ref ip, port, 0);
        }

        public static void initObject(int machineNumber, string ip, int port, string name)
        {
            _Machine = new AxSBXPCLib.AxSBXPC();
            _Machine.CreateControl();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to create the object of class DUMMY, it works fine until I get an error like so:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/5/ROOT-1-130601790500037206): Loaded    'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_pt_b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Http.dll
```

I tried STAThread, creating a new thread, and other solutions however, none of them works.

Any ideas?

PS: I tried working with the object by itself, and it works fine in another project (Console application). I was able to place [STAThread] at the Main function of the program, but in this case I can't seem to make it work...

EDIT:

I tested with a non AxHost object:

```
namespace AccessControl.Objects
{
    public class DUMMY
    {
        private static SBXPCLib.SBXPC _Machine;

        public DUMMY(int machineNumber, string ip, int port, string name)
        {
            initObject(machineNumber, ip, port, name);
            _Machine.ConnectTcpip(machineNumber, ref ip, port, 0);
        }

        public static void initObject(int machineNumber, string ip, int port, string name)
        {
            _Machine = new SBXPCLib.SBXPC();
        }
    }
}
```

And it gives me another error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Http.dll
```

While debugging, "_Machine" takes the COM Object as seen in the picture:

[Picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByVfzIeD0xmXT1FEakhyaENraFk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Static constructors are hard to debug, so maybe try moving the code into another method and calling it manually during application start. With a breakpoint you might get more info.

Comment: So I tried using a non static method, but it didn't work, same error. I tried creating the object in another part of the code, still the same error... So it's no use. Thanks for the idea, though...